# Internet Explorer 8 form auto login

Tags: internet-explorer, login, html, javascript, web-development

How can I configure Internet Explorer 8 to automatically log in to an intranet application form when I visit the application address ?

Is there a add-on for this or a setting that I have to make ?

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is old, but since no one has responded I will try. Since you are talking Internet Explorer and intranet, I am going to assume that you are also using Active Directory.

As far as I know, there is no setting in Internet Explorer that will set this up. If you have control of the server, then you can change the settings in IIS to allow Windows authentication. Then, depending on exactly what you are trying to do, you would need to do some programming on the application to read your Active Directory information. Also, you would need to make sure that the URL for the intranet application does not have any dots (.) in it, because then the automatic authentication will not be applied.